# CakePHP edit timestamp without time

Tags: php, cakephp, timestamp

I am looking for a way to edit a timestamp field without displaying the time to it. Right now we are using this code to edit the field:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Kongress.beginn', array('size' => false,
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'timeFormat' => '24'));
```

Is there a way to do the exact same thing, but without displaying the time?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to be able to edit the field but to start with a blank value, you could use a different name for the field and update the value before calling the `save()` method.

view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Kongress.beginn_new', array('size' => false,
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'timeFormat' => '24'));
```

controller:

```
$this->request->data['Kongress']['beginn'] = $this->request->data['Kongress']['beginn_new'];

$this->Kongress->save($this->request->data);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, the goal is to be able to edit the field, which has already been set